# Trying to use replaceFirst to add values to a querystring parameter field

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

I have added a JSR223 PreProcessor on a HTTP Sampler with the intention of being able to select a querystring parameter and add a new value to it. 
i.e.:

**BEFORE**
`designer=17827&size=3350&color=1`

*Selected parameter = Size*
*New value to add = 9999*

**AFTER**
`designer=17827&size=3350|9999&color=1`

In order to do it I developed the Groovy code below:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

def listing_page_filter_name = "size";
def filter_values_value = "9999";
def listing_filters = "designer=17827&size=3350&color=1";

def prefix = listing_page_filter_name;
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(prefix + '=(.+?)&|' + prefix + '=(.+?)\\$');
String pattern = r.toString();
//Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(listing_filters);

log.info("FILTER: " + listing_page_filter_name);
log.info("FILTER VALUE: " + filter_values_value);

if(m.find())
{
        log.info("Found value ------>  " + m.group(1));
        def regex_match = m.group(1);
        def replacement = regex_match + "|" + filter_values_value;
        log.info('Replacing it by: $1' + replacement);
        String str = m.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(pattern),Pattern.quote(replacement));
        log.info(str);
        //log.info(m.replaceFirst(/=(.+?)&|/,"lalalalalalala"));
}
```

The output I am having is:

```
2019-05-15 11:28:02,765 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: RANDOMLY CHOSEN FILTER: size
2019-05-15 11:28:02,765 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: RANDOMLY CHOSEN FILTER VALUE: 9999
2019-05-15 11:28:02,765 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: Found value ------>  3350
2019-05-15 11:28:02,766 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: Replacing it by: $13350|9999
2019-05-15 11:28:02,766 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceFirst() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [\Qsize=(.+?)&|size=(.+?)\$\E, \Q3350|9999\E]
Possible solutions: replaceFirst(java.lang.String)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:935) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:537) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceFirst() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [\Qsize=(.+?)&|size=(.+?)\$\E, \Q3350|9999\E]
Possible solutions: replaceFirst(java.lang.String)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:48) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at Script36.run(Script36.groovy:23) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    ... 9 more
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no replaceFirst method for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the info @daggett . Do you know how could I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

for me it's easier is not to use regexp:

```
def q0 = "designer=17827&size=3350&color=1"
def q1 = q0.split('&').collect{ 
    it.split('=').with{ 
        if(it[0]=='size'){
            it[1]=it[1] + '|6641'
        }
        return it.join('=')
    }
}.join('&')
println q1
```

but for your case it's even simpler to use replaceAll or replaceFirst:

```
def q0 = "designer=17827&size=3350&color=1"
def key='designer'
def append = '|5555'
def q1 = q0.replaceAll('('+key+'=)([^&]*)', '$1$2'+append)
println q1
```